# Rails exception - "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a partial for my entity *requirement* which has an attribute of *name*. *Requirements* are associated to *Projects*. I am trying to render this partial for *Requirements* on the *Project* show page. I get the following error on load.

> NoMethodError in Projects#show
> Showing .....xus/app/views/requirements/_requirement.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

In my partial, _requirement.html.erb

```
<%= div_for requirement do %>
  <h4>
    <%= requirement.name  %>
  </h4>
  <%= requirement.requirement_type.name %>
  <%= requirement.requirement_priority.name %>
  <%= simple_format requirement.detail %>
<% end %>
```

The relevant section of my Project show template

```
<h3>Project Requirements</h3>
<div id="requirements_display">
  <%= render :partial => "requirements/requirement", :locals => {:requirement => @requirement} %>
</div>

<div id="requirements_module">
<h3>Add New Requirement</h3>
<%= render :file => "requirements/new" %>
</div>
```

I also tried rendering the partial using

```
<h3>Project Requirements</h3>
<div id="requirements_display">
  <%= render @project.requirements %>
</div>
```

But not look there, either. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: The error is complaining that `requirement.requirement_type` is nil, and yet you're trying to call `.name` on it. What is requirement_type?  From your description, it sounds like you meant to put just `requirement.requirement_type` instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. requirement_type is another entity/model, basically a 'category'. Every requirement is assigned a requirement_type. When I run it without the .name method, it prints out "#<RequirementType:0x102fdc110> #<RequirementPriority:0x102fd78b8>" onto the template. I've also tested the relationship in the console and the relationships are in fact intact. For some reason the .name method isn't catching.

Comment: What does your Projects#show look like ?

Comment: I've had many problems trying to pass parameters into partials.  A couple of trouble shooting ideas:   Can you successfully use "@requirement.name" in your partial?  Does your partial code work if you move it back up into the main view and convert it to using "@requirement"?  Are you sure "@requirement" is not coming in from your controller as nil?

Comment: Thank you for all of the responses. Check below, I uncovered the problem. I had previously created a @requirement in the Show method of my Project which was creating an empty requirement with no reference. After removing that everything linked up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue! Some legacy code in my controller was creating an empty @requirement which was bugging things up!